# Making Engine: Lib class not found: unitialized constant (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm build a gem and created:

"/lib/gem_name/resource.rb"

```
module GemName
  class Resource
    def initialize
      # nothing
    end
  end
end
```

and in "/lib/gem_name.rb"

```
require "gem_name/engine"

module GemName
  def new_resource
    @resources << GemName::Resource.new
  end
end
```

in "/test/dummy/config/initializers/gem_name.rb"

```
GemName.new_resource
```

when I start console, show this message:

`unitialized constant GemName::Resource (NameError)`

I check gem_name.gemspec and its contents is:

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)

# Maintain your gem's version:
require "gem_name/version"

# Describe your gem and declare its dependencies:
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "gem_name"
  s.version     = GemName::VERSION
  s.authors     = ["TODO: Your name"]
  s.email       = ["TODO: Your email"]
  s.homepage    = "TODO"
  s.summary     = "TODO: Summary of GemName."
  s.description = "TODO: Description of GemName."

  s.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib}/**/*"] + ["MIT-LICENSE", "Rakefile", "README.rdoc"]
  s.test_files = Dir["test/**/*"]

  s.add_dependency "rails", "~> 3.2.8"
  # s.add_dependency "jquery-rails"

  s.add_development_dependency "sqlite3"
end
```

Environment spec:

- ruby 1.9.2
- rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to require `gem_name/resource` directly in "/lib/gem_name.rb" file?